# How do I load this jQuery to my wordpress page?

Tags: jquery

I hope you can help me, I've scoured the internet for hours and can't seem to make this work. I'm trying to follow these directions for using MixItUp: https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/learn/tutorial/get-started/

The HTML and the CSS show up correctly. But I can't get the jQuery to load. I've looked at other answers and several tutorial sites, tweaking the code here and there, but still nothing happens.

This is all that's in my file *custom.js* (I've changed the id/class 'Container' to 'projects' because I already have a Container class)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('#projects').mixItUp();
});
```

This is in my *functions.php*

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
function add_my_script() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'projects', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
}
```

and I need to call the MixItUp js file, I've tried wp_enqueue_script ing it in the *functions.php*. I've tried pasting this

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.mixitup/latest/jquery.mixitup.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

in the *footer.php* right before the `</body>` tag, I tried it in the individual page editor, in the *header.php*...

I am probably missing something so glaringly obvious! I'm new to coding so I don't understand. Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: When you say you can't get the jQuery to load, do you mean the files don't load or just that you don't see the effect you want? What HTML are you using and what do you want to happen?

Comment: You're on the right track with wp_enqueue_scripts. Don't just put them all in your footer file, amongst other things you run the risk of loading more than one jQuery.

Comment: Including your HTML in your question might be helpful. It'll help everyone here understand whether it's the loading of the file or the effect of the jQuery the actual problem.

Comment: And in your footer.php you refer to main.js and not to custom.js. What's in main.js?

Answer (score 0):

I would download the jquery.mixitup.min.js and place it in the same folder as your custom script (js), also makes sense to place the "main.js" file in there also, keeping your js together, if you can.

Not sure if your using a child theme or not,if not but add the following to your functions file, overwriting your original code:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
function add_my_script() {
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js',array(), '1.0.0',false );
wp_enqueue_script( 'projects', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js',array(),false,false );

}
```